# latex popup box answer

Tags: beamer, slideshow

I'm making a class notes slides for a math course, and some slides contains some exercises. After writing the exercise I want to make a pop up box which contain the solution for that exercise, but I have a problem in doing this.

For example, I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme[width=1.4cm]{PaloAlto}      
  \usecolortheme{beaver} 
  \usefonttheme{default}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Chapter One}
Find the domain of the function:
$$  f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}-4}$$

Solution.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When clicking on "Solution" I want a popup box to appear and contain the solution

```
$x^{2}-4 \geq 0, x^{2}\geq 4, |x|\geq 2$
```

Answer (score 2):

You could show the solution on the next overlay:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme[width=1.4cm]{PaloAlto}      
  \usecolortheme{beaver} 
  \usefonttheme{default}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Chapter One}
Find the domain of the function:
\[  f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}-4}\]
\pause
\begin{block}{Solution}
\[x^{2}-4 \geq 0, x^{2}\geq 4, |x|\geq 2\]
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Or if more questions should follow:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme[width=1.4cm]{PaloAlto}      
  \usecolortheme{beaver} 
  \usefonttheme{default}
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Chapter One}
Find the domain of the function:
\[  f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}-4}\]

\begin{onlyenv}<+(1)>
  \begin{block}{Solution}
  \[x^{2}-4 \geq 0, x^{2}\geq 4, |x|\geq 2\]
  \end{block}
\end{onlyenv}

\pause 
next quiz
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Off-topic:

- you don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer
- don't us `$$...$$`, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: So I should click next to show the solution box! Is there any way to just click on the word "Solution" to show the solution box, because there will be other exercises in that slide and I only need to pop up one box solution at a time.

Comment: @John Please see my second solution

Comment: The second solution force you to move along the exercises one  by one to show the solution to a particular exercise in a list of many exercises, and this will be a little tedious. It would be more flexible if just click on a button near any selected exercise to view its solution as a pop up box.

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is low, no comment allowed. Thus I have to answer: Give `fancytooltips` a try.

Comment: Worked a bit on your reputation, so you soon can convert your answer into a comment :-)

Comment: You can [comment on anything when you have 50 reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) (which you have).

Comment: @Werner: But only after this answer!